# In an increasing sequence of 4 positive integers,the first 3 terms form an AP and the last 3 terms form a GP. If the 4th and 1st term differ by 30,

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the terms.
 AP is arithmetic progression and GP is geometric progression. This question is reducing to 1 equation in 2 variable in my method . So 8 cant determine the sequence. Please help.

Comment: like $18, 27, 36, 48?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the sequence be $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$.

If the first three terms are in arithmetic progression, there is an integer $k$ with
$$
a_2 = a_1+k\;\;\;;\;\;\;a_3 = a_1+2k
$$
If the last 3 terms are in geometric progression, then
$$
a_4 = \frac{a_3^2}{a_2} = \frac{(a_1+2k)^2}{a_1+k}.
$$ 
Lastly, the first and last terms differ by $30$, so $a_4 = a_1 + 30$. Putting this together, we have
$$
a_1 + 30 = \frac{(a_1+2k)^2}{a_1+k} \Longrightarrow a_1 = \frac{2k (15 - 2 k)}{3 (k-10)}
$$
That expression is only positive for $7.5 < k < 10$, and the only integers in that range are $8$ and $9$. $8$ doesn't work, so we must have $k = 9$. Thus, $a_1 = 18$ and the sequence is
$$
18,27,36,48
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the sequence be $$ar^2-30,a,ar,ar^2$$

Now we have $$2a=ar^2-30+ar\iff ar^2+ar-2a-30=0$$

The discriminant needs to be square of a rational number to keep $r$ rational

But as $a$ is an integer, the discriminant will actually be a perfect square of an integer

$9a^2+120a=(3a+20)^2-20^2=c^2$(say)

$20^2=(3a+20-c)(3a+20+c)$

As the multiplicands in the right hand side have the same parity, both must be even

$10^2=\dfrac{3a+20-c}2\cdot\dfrac{3a+20+c}2$

As $a\ge2,$

$c^2=3a(3a+40)\ge6(6+40),c>16$

$\dfrac{3a+20+c}2>\dfrac{6+20+16}2>21$

So, it can be one of $25,50,100$

Try with the three cases